Example of Pali Tripitaka in PDF online (How does it's layout look)?
A while back I asked How is the romanized Pali Tipitaka on tipitaka.org formatted? and now I am back at it, trying to reason through how the XML on tipitaka.org is organized. I would like to see an example of the Pali Tripitaka text online as a PDF or book of some sort, to see how they handled the "headers problem", to see if they include all the same headers that the tipitaka.org XML does, or if they do it differently in books, etc..
Would you mind sharing 1, 2, or 3 examples of the Pali Tripitaka in different formats (older copies, so we can look at how it was organized and printed before the web)?
I would like to publish a modern version of the Tripitaka online, but need to first better understand how the previous publishers of various sorts organized the content (headings, subheadings, chapter labels, etc.).
